# overridefeature in XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, overriding

Is there a way to override the value of  base complextypes value in XSD ?. To be more clear,

i have my base complex type as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="Urn:commonBase"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="Urn:commonBase"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="RequestBase">
    <xs:attribute name="Version" default="1.0"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and in another XSD and a different namespace i have

```
<xs:complexType name="Request">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="base:RequestBase">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name ="FirstName"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="Version" fixed="2.0"/>
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

But when i generate the C# class file for the above using XSD.exe, a duplicate property is generated with the name  "Version**1**" . i actually want an override facility in the class file which set the existing property of "RequestBase" from 1.0 to 2.0 and not a extra property. How to acheive this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a restriction step to restrict the value of the 'Version' attribute from any simple type to '2.0', then an extension step to add the 'FirstName' element.

(*Note that by fixing the value of 'Version' at '2.0' you make it impossible for anyone to base a version 3.0 type on your version 2.0 type in the way you're basing your 2.0 type on the 1.0 type.  Do you really want to stick your thumb in the eye of the next guy in line that way?*)

Comment: so you mean to say that i need to introduce a simple type in between. :(. i was trying for any possible way in which i can do it togehter ..